# How to remove button in Sublime Text 4 from context menu?

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, sublimetext4

I would like to remove button "Remove folder from Project" sometimes I accidentally click on this button and have to re-create the project. I think Sublime pretty flexible editor that allows to remove or add some features.

[image]

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but it takes a few steps. We'll be creating a file override.

1. Select **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`** (macOS: **`:Sublime Text → Preferences → Browse Packages…`**) to open your `Packages` directory:

   - Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages` or `~/.config/sublime-text/Packages`
   - OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` or `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Packages`
   - Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages` or `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages`
   - Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages` `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text\Data\Packages`

   <sup>The exact path depends on version and whether or not you upgraded from Sublime Text 3.</sup>
2. In that directory, create a directory called `Default`. Make sure it's capitalized.
3. Back in Sublime, open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> or **`Tools → Command Palette`**) and type `v`, then select `View Package File`.
4. Type in `def side mount` (it's a fuzzy search) and select `Default/Side Bar Mount Point.sublime-menu`.
5. Select **`View → Show Console`** to open the Sublime Python console. Type in

   ```py
   view.set_read_only(False)
   ```

   and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now we can edit and save the file.
6. On line 3 of the file, add 2 forward slashes (`//`) at the very beginning of the line to comment out that line. The file should now look like this:

   ```json
   [
       { "caption": "-", "id": "folder_commands" },
   //  { "caption": "Remove Folder from Project", "command": "remove_folder", "args": { "dirs": []} }
   ]
   ```
7. Select **`File → Save As…`**. Navigate to the `Packages/Default` directory you made in Step 2, and save the file there. Make sure you don't change its name.
8. Although the change should go into effect immediately, restart Sublime Text just to make sure. The `Remove Folder from Project` option should no longer show up when you right-click on a folder in the Side Bar.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and accurate answer. You saved my projects from further re-creation :)